# A square matrix $A$ such that $AA_{*j}=0$ for every $j$ must be zero

Tags: matrices

True or False?
If the square matrix $A=[A_{*1},A_{*2},...A_{*n}]$ has the property that $AA_{*j}=0$ for every $j$, then $A=0$.
Note that $A_{*j}$ denotes the $j$th column in the matrix $A$.

Not really sure how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

False. Consider $A = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -1\\ 1 & -1\end{array}\right]$.

Comment: Or the nilpotent Jordan block $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$, which I think is a more classical example.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $b_1,..,b_n$ column vectors and $B=[b_1|\dots|b_n]$ is the matrix out of them, then by the matrix multiplication rule, we get
$$AB=[Ab_1\,|\,Ab_2\,|\dots|\,Ab_n]$$
(of course, if the dimension of $b_i$'s equals to the number of columns of $A$).

So, we are talking about the question $A^2=0 \overset{?}{\implies} A=0$.

Comment: still confused? Why would I add another matrix B? Aren't I only dealing with the one matrix?

Comment: @mike Berci is trying to explain that your problem is equivalent to asking whether $A^2=0$ implies $A=0$.

Comment: It's a general useful rule. You're right, in this case you need only the $B=A$ case. The other answer gives you examples for $2\times 2$ matrices $A\ne 0$ with $A^2=0$.